# How to get rule to fire only once?

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine, kie

Assuming the following rule which listens to events with a specific identifier. Only one event per identifier should be handled.

```
rule "SampleRule"
dialect "mvel"
no-loop true
when
    Event( $identifier : identifier)
    not(EventHandler( identifier == $identifier )) 
then
    EventHandler $h = new EventHandler();
    $h.setIdentifier( $identifier );
    insert( $h );
end
```

Event class:

```
...

@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.kie.api.definition.type.Role(org.kie.api.definition.type.
                         Role.Type.EVENT) // line break just for SO
public class Event implements java.io.Serializable {

  static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(generator = "STATUSNOTIFICATION_ID_GENERATOR", strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO)
  @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "STATUSNOTIFICATION_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "STATUSNOTIFICATION_ID_SEQ")
  private java.lang.Long id;

  private java.lang.String identifier;

  public Event() {
  }

  public java.lang.String getIdentifier() {
    return this.identifier;
  }

  public void setIdentifier(java.lang.String identifier) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
  }
}
```

Event class is configured via Drools Workbench. Besides declaring the class as EVENT, I did not change anything else.

The way events get inserted into rules engine:

```
KieServicesConfiguration conf = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(
            url, user, pass);
conf.setMarshallingFormat(FORMAT);   
KieServicesClient kieServicesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(conf);
RuleServicesClient rulesClient = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class); 
KieCommands commandsFactory = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();

while (hasEvent) {
  String identifier = ... // get the identifier of the event, events with same identifier possible, sometimes within same seconds, sometimes several minutes/hours in between

  Event event = new Event();
  event.setIdentifier(identifier);

  Command<?> insert = commandsFactory.newInsert(event, "notificationIdentifier");
  Command<?> fireAllRules = commandsFactory.newFireAllRules();
  Command<?> batchCommand = commandsFactory.newBatchExecution(Arrays.asList(insert, fireAllRules));

  ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> executeResponse = rulesClient.executeCommandsWithResults("name_of_rules_package_incl_version", batchCommand);
  if (executeResponse.getType() == ResponseType.SUCCESS) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }  
}
```

Besides the "SampleRule" rule above I have one more rule enabled which retracts Events from working memory if an EventHandler per identifier exists:

```
rule "SampleRuleClear"
dialect "mvel"
no-loop true
when
    $E : Event( $identifier : identifier)
    EventHandler( identifier == $identifier )
then
    retract( $E ); 
end
```

Actually "SampleRuleClear" rule should not be required to prevent duplicates. I just mention it here for completeness.

I expect the "SampleRule" rule to fire only once per event per identifier. Unfortunately,  it fires multiple times, even if events are widely spaced.

Comment: Is this the only rule you have in your `KieBase`? Could you share with us the definition of the Event class (it is a Drools event?) and the way you are inserting your objects into your session?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti I added more details. Thanks for your time!